# Existe como alterar um programa padrão por java, cmd ou regedit?

Tags: java, windows, cmd

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema em java, porém a partir dele eu deveria alterar o programa padrão para abrir .pdf no comutador. No Windows 10 ele abre por padrão no Edge, porém a partir do sistema ele deve alterar para o Adobe.

Já tentei pelo cmd com o comando assoc (reiniciando o computador depois):

```
assoc .pdf=AcrodRd32.exe
```

ou

```
assoc .pdf=AcroExch.Document.DC
```

Também já tentei através do regedit com o script (também reiniciando o computador depois):

```
===================
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.pdf]
@=".pdf=AcroExch.Document.DC"
"Content Type"="application/pdf"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.pdf\OpenWithList]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.pdf\OpenWithList\AcrodRd32.exe]
@=""
===================
```

Testei o script em HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.pdf\ quanto em HKEY_CLASSES_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts
porém nenhum funcionou.

Acredito que direto pelo java não tenha nenhuma forma de alterar. Alguém tem alguma ideia de como fazer essa alteração ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Esse site mostra algo não muito animador.](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2015/05/20/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-10122-for-pcs/#cH0JpBZ4E85KYCxJ.97)

Parece que a partir do Windows 10, essa funcionalidade foi removida:

> "Nós sabemos que os programas padrão são importantes pra você. No Windows 10, todos os aplicativos - tanto Clássicos quanto Universais - não poderão mostrar uma janela perguntando se você quer trocar seu programa padrão - só o Windows." - *Traduzido do inglês*

Talvez fazendo um aplicativo clássico (não sei exatamente se isso significa apenas compilar para sistemas mais antigos ou não) você consiga ainda se aproveitar deste *prompt*:

[image: prompt ensinando o usuário a mudar o programa padrão]

Mas de qualquer maneira ele só irá "ensinar" o usuário a trocar o programa padrão e não "oferecer" para trocar automaticamente.

Mesmo assim, em Java isso não é possível sem algumas "gambiarras", pois o .jar não é um aplicativo Windows válido. Uma possível solução é transformar o .jar num .exe - [esse programa](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/) não só cria um executável de um .jar como também diz [definir o programa padrão](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/default-programs.html).

Mas acho que estamos sem sorte!

Fontes no Soen:
[Set default program for extension after msi installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39687918/set-default-program-for-extension-after-msi-installation)
[Use a Java application as the Default Program for a particular file type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9632793/use-a-java-application-as-the-default-program-for-a-particular-file-type)

Comment: Pois é, estamos sem sorte mesmo. Realmente tudo que testei foi no Windows 10, mas nada funcionou. Vou tentar em versões anteriores, porém todos os computador aqui da empresa são Windows 10 então não vai resolver. Mesmo assim obrigado!